# Symfony2: why does my time field not validate on the live server

Tags: datetime, symfony

I have following form field (defined in a formType):

```
->add('startDate','datetime',array(
                'required' => false,
                'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                'time_widget' => 'single_text',
            ));
```

Weird thing: on my local dev machine, everything works just as expected, when I input some time (like "09:33"). On the live server however, the form tells me on save, that the value is not valid. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? It's weird that you don't get the same error on dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that Intl is not configured with the same locale on your live server and dev machine.

By default, Intl*Formatters will use `\Locale::getDefault()` value. You have to configure it poperly, using app/config/config.yml for example:

```
framework:
    default_locale: en
```

Comment: I switched the default_locale while testing, and forgot to switch back again. Since the locale is set on login, clearing the cache on the server did not help. Logout and login did!

Answer (score 0):

> `single_text`: renders a single input of type text. User's input is validated based on the format [option](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/date.html#format).

You are not specifying the `format` option which says it defaults to `IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM` ([example](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php#intl.intldateformatter-constants): `Jan 12, 1952`).

> Option passed to the `IntlDateFormatter` class, used to transform user input into the proper format. **This is critical when the widget option is set to single_text, and will define how the user will input the data.** By default, the format is determined based on the current user locale; you can override it by passing the format as a string.

Perhaps you should try setting the `format` option and also compare the locale settings on your local machine and production server.